# Google Sheets: Find Row In a Column That Last Had A Larger Value Than The Current Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Updated:** While the solution provided `=IF(A2>A1,IF(A2>MAX(A$1:A1),ROW()-1,IFERROR(B1+1,1)),1)` does work for the original test data, it doesn't work for a more complex data set, see the second screen shot below:

---

Original question:

I have a need to process a column (A in the example) of numbers that represents a value changing over time, and establish for how many rows the present row's number has been the largest number, and report that as illustrated in Column B.

What I can't figure out is whether there is a way of producing column B using spreadsheet functions or if I need to write some apps script to do the calculations. I've looked at the usual suspects like MAX() and LARGE() but they don't quite do what I want.

What I want is something like MAXSINCE(A99, A:A98) but that doesn't exist.[image]

### Updated data set which still doesn't have an answer for the question: for how many rows has this row had the largest value?

[image: More Complex data set]

Comment: Should be a simple enough script to write into a custom function. you'd want to make sure it takes a range argument, and returns a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Logic Flow:

- Check if current value `A2` is greater than previous value `A1`; If not, return 1
- If the above is true, Check whether current value is greater than the present `MAX`. If so, return current `ROW`'s number - starting offset `1` else add 1 to previous value `B1`

#### Code Sample:

B2:

```
=IF(A2>A1,IF(A2>MAX(A$1:A1),ROW()-1,IFERROR(B1+1,1)),1)
```

Drag fill down

Comment: Thank you, thought there would be a way!

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for a more complex data set; I've updated the questions.